# tell whether they are covariance matrix

Tags: covariance

If A and B are co-variance matrix, is A+B a co-variance matrix?  Is A^2 a co-variance matrix?  Is AB a co-variance matrix?

I know the necessary properties of covariance matrix, but I did not know the sufficient properties of covariance matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Also, think covariance matrix of *what*? Eg, are you asking if the covariance matrix of the sum of a matrix A + a matrix B has a covariance matrix equal to the covariance matrix of A + the covariance matrix of B?

Comment: This is an interview question.

Answer (score 1):

In order for an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ to be a valid covariance matrix, $M$ must be symmetric and positive semidefinite.  Knowing that $A$ and $B$ are covariance matrices (and have all the properties of a covariance matrix), you should construct general matrices $A$ and $B$ that are covariance matrices (but assume nothing else) and see if $A+B$, $A^2$ and $AB$ satisfy the above conditions for a covariance matrix. (That is, are $A+B$, $A^2$, and $AB$ $n\times n$, symmetric, and positive definite?)

Comment: So I can see that A+B, A^2 and AB are all symmetric.  A+B I can see is positive semidefinite, but I am not sure about A^2 and AB. Could you enlighten on them? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think that's the purpose of the problem as it's posed to you. :) In the same way that you checked whether or not $A+B$ is positive semidefinite (also called non-negative definite), try to check $A^2$ and $AB$.  Look at the definition of positive semidefinite and see if it makes sense.  Oftentimes I try to find a counterexample for a minute or two in order to convince me if my conjecture seems to hold up.

Comment: AB I have a counter-example A=[1,-1][-1,1], B=[1,1][1,1],  AB=[0], so AB is not a covariance matrix.  A^2 I am not sure.